# Bind List with dynamically returned columns

Tags: c#, list, wcf-rest

I am writing WCF service. The output of my sql query will return me different no of columns everytime based on table selected. I bind the result of sql query to my list. Now i dont know how do i bind list with dynamically returned columns. Here is my service.

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "MyService")]
    public List<TableList> GetTableListy(Parameters param)
    {
        try
        {
            var myReturnList = new List<LookUpSystemTable>();
            var passedVersionId = int.Parse((param.VersionId));
            var Name = param.Name();              
            var fromDate = param.FromDate.ToShortDateString();
            var toDate = param.ToDate.ToShortDateString();
            string selectedColumnNames = "";
            var PickupList= from t in _TableEntityRepository.AsQueryable()
                                  where t.Name.Equals(Name)
                                  select t.columns;

            var foriegnKeyCol = "k" + Name.Substring(1);

            string columnNames = PickupList.FirstOrDefault();

            if (columnNames != null){
                selectedColumnNames = GetBetween(columnNames.ToUpper(),"SELECT " , " FROM");
                selectedColumnNames = selectedColumnNames.Replace("\n", string.Empty);
            }

                var fromQuery =
                   "select " + selectedColumnNames + "  from  " + tableName  +
                    " t  Where t.FromDate <= '" + fromDate +  "' and  t.Id = " +
                   Id ;


            IEnumerable<MyClass> ListOfTables = Context.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>(fromQuery);

             foreach (var t in ListOfTables )
                {


                   // How do i assign dynamically created column returned from sqlquery


                }

            }

         return null;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new WebFaultException<string>(
        string.Format(
            "{0}{1}",
            e.Message, (e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : string.Empty)), HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }


    }
```

My class for TableList is

```
public class TableList 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Any one has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you explore `DataTable` possibility? It allows dynamic columns.

Or use anonymous objects with dynamic properties via SQL LINQ.

[Dynamic query data from WCF Data Service to Silverlight Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989465/dynamic-query-data-from-wcf-data-service-to-silverlight-application)

Comment: Can you share something with me regarding it?

Comment: Also would be nice if you can tell me how to use in my scenario

Comment: Is it possible to return datatable via WCF service?

Comment: Also currently i have used List like public List<TableList> GetTableListy(Parameters param)

so now i could use public Datatable GetTableListy(parameters param)

Am i correct?

Comment: I tried to google and no one is suggesting to return datable as good practise. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380630/returning-datatable-objects-with-wcf-service

Comment: WCF should return dataclasses but then they cannot have dynamic columns. If you need dynmaic columns you should use datatable. If you cant achieve both then you should look into anonymous objects with dynamic properties... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989465/dynamic-query-data-from-wcf-data-service-to-silverlight-application

Comment: @WPFIT i am looking into datatables. But i cant figure out how can i filter datatable and show distinct record based on id and latest date. Do you have any idea?